# error when installing ADT plugin 'Cannot complete the install '

Tags: eclipse

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

```
  Software being installed: 
Android Native Development Tools 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819 
(com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.group 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819)
```

Software details:

```
Eclipse SDK : 4.2
jdk-7-windows-i586
Windows 7
```

How can I fix this 'required items could not be found' error?

Comment: Please check this answer, I had the same problem and it worked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12107559/752781

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are using Windows 7 and in Windows 7,by default admin permissions are not available.

So just right click on Eclipse icon and choose "Run as Administrator" and then click on Help  -> Install new software -> Then paste URL of ADT plugin -> Click on Select All-> Next-> Finish  and it will continue installing

Answer (score 2):

When installing ADT through Eclipse just make sure you have checked: Contact all update sites during install to find required software. That helped me.

Also try to update eclipse (Help -> Check for updates)

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and download the "Eclipse for Mobile Developers" version. Then follow the installation steps for the ADT plugin.