# Installing ADT on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins

This kind of speaks for itself...

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

**Software being installed: Android Native Development Tools 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819** (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.group 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819)

**Missing requirement: Android Native Development Tools 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819** (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.group 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819) requires 'org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Did somebody else had the same problem ? Google tells me to install the plugin manually.

[ADT Installation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Comment: Never encountered that error, installation always went fine. I understand that doesn't help though.

Comment: Since when is there an Eclipse plugin for NDK?

Answer (score 46):

I had this problem too, and I solved it by the next way.

1. Go to Help, "Install New Software..."
2. Click on "Available Sofware Sites"
3. Search `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo` and enable it
4. Search `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/indigo` and enable it
5. Come back to Help, "Install New Software..."
6. Check "Contact all update sites during install to find requiered sofware"
7. Install ADT Plugin
8. IT MUST WORK!!!

Comment: In my version of eclipse, I had to enable "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno" and there was no "http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/indigo" so I skipped fourth step.

Comment: Wow! This helped fix the issue I was facing. @Waseem it should be `../cdt/releases/juno`.

Comment: Replace `indigo` with `kepler` for both URLs, if you're targeting the kepler version of Eclipse.

Comment: Is there any way to download/install manually the required packages ?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone needs it, I had the same problem and solved it.
It was the missing repositories that were the issue. 
For Juno I just went to "Install new software" > click "Add" and enter Juno as name and "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno" in location. After that everything works.

Answer (score 1):

The installation may go smoother if you start with Eclipse IDE for C Developers. That package already includes CDT plugins.

Alternative, try the following:

1. In the install wizard, look for "Available Software Sites" link. Click on it. Make sure that you see a repository listed with a URL like "http/download.eclipse.org/releases/juno". And that that listing is enabled. The last segment of the URL can very depending on the version of Eclipse you have... ganymede, helios, indigo, juno.
2. Back in the install dialog, ensure that "contact all update sites..." checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this. Did you fully install the Android SDK (Is there anything in your platform folder)? I realized I had some things missing because I couldn't reach the https source.  I had to launch the Android SDK Manager and check a box for "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://"  to be sure I was seeing all files I needed to install for the SDK.

Also, in Eclipse Help->Install New Software, make sure you check "Show only software applicable to target environment"

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eclipse for Java!
Just make sure you had checked "Contact all updates..." option.
It'll work flawless!