# Can't see Generate Gradle build files when migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle-eclipse

I tried the instructions listed here http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html#Export, including upgrading my adt plugin (I simply checked for updates in Eclipse, per http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html#Updating ; it said I was up to date). But when I tried to export projects from Eclipse I don't see the "Generate Gradle build files" option, only "Export Android Application."

[image]

Is there something more that I have to do to see this option? I am using the Android Developer Tools version for Mac, Build: v21.1.0-569685.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I can't just check for updates like the developer's site said for the ADT: I still have ADT version 21. Reinstalling ADT works.

This question has some useful info on updating to ADT 22  [Can't update Eclipse ADT to 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585315/cant-update-eclipse-adt-to-22).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the "Generate Gradle build files" option installed ADT version must be v22 or higher. To solve the fact that when you go to "Help/Check for Updates" it says "Up to date" while you have v21 you can either reinstall Eclipse ADT or follow the instructions in the link below, using [ADT22.zip](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.0.0.zip):

[Eclipse ADT update does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022622/eclipse-adt-update-does-not-work)