# can not update ADT from 22.3.0 to 22.6.2

Tags: android, adt

I just updated android SDK tool to 22.6.2 version through android SDK Manager.

when restart eclipse, it says i need to update ADT to latest version.

I have referenced：
this thread:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67325.
this thread:
[Error Message : This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.1 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513524/error-message-this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-22-6).
and this thread : [Can't update Eclipse ADT to 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585315/cant-update-eclipse-adt-to-22).

and of cause the official documents : 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

none of these solutions works for me.

i can't update adt online even I setp up proxy by goagent, it always saying pending

i can't update adt through the ADT Plugin zip file, it always saying calculating requirements and dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Check out my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15022823/944070

Do not skip `Step 2` where you uncheck the box `Contact all update sites during install to find required software`

Comment: i unchecked the box you mentioned. it does proceed to next step saying like "xxx" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead. and next step I agree, next step, intalling software, and then it blocks there