# ADT Plugin: Installed the new version but it´s still the old one

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I installed the new Android SDK Tools (22.6.2) and now I have to install a new Version of my ADT plugin. So I did the following steps:

-) I went in Eclips to Help/Install New Software and downloadet from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse the new ADP Version (22.6.2)

-) I installed all of them and then I restarted eclips.

But then I still get the error message, that I have to install the ADT vesion 22.6.2, even if I installed it just some seconds ago?!

If I select Help/About ADP it also says, that I still have the older Version installed.

If I want to install the Version 22.6.2 again, it always says that it is already installed but it isn´t!

Please help.

Comment: check your adt path @ window->preferences->Android

Comment: Try the top answer given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022622/eclipse-adt-update-does-not-work).

Comment: Try the top answer,if that doesn't work then update eclipse to latest version