# "No repository found" - updating of Android ADT via Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have the `Android SDK/ADT` bundle installed, with Eclipse running. First odd thing is, when I click "Check for updates" it says there are none available.  Although when I instead click "Install new software" and select the built-in android dl site, there IS an update to the ADT available, which is slightly newer than what's installed. Anyway that's not my problem.. So, I checkmark the available update(s), and try to install it. After a couple minutes of progress, I get the following error message:

```
  [Problem Occurred] 'Installing Software' has encountered a problem. An error occurred while collecting items to be installed -----(I click 'Details' and this is what is shown): session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=). 
    No repository found containing:osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
    No repository found containing:osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
   No repository found containing:osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
    No repository found containing:osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
    No repository found containing:osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
   No repository found containing:osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
    No repository found containing:osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
    No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
    No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
    No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
    No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview,22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206
```

Can anybody please help me identify the problem, and how to fix it?
I would greatly appreciate some help with this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the site you checked on.

Comment: Have you tried that? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15022823/944070

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes, updating directly from Developer.android.com generally gives these kind of issues. As mentioned in [android site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) **"Troubleshooting ADT Installation"**, please download the zip "ADT-22.6.3.zip" and do NOT UNZIP it.

Then, follow below steps:

- Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
- Click Add, in the top-right corner. In the Add Repository dialog, click Archive.
- Select the downloaded ADT-22.6.3.zip file and click OK.
- Enter "ADT Plugin" for the name and click OK.
- In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
- In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
- Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
- If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
- When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

**To update your plugin once you've installed using the zip file, you will have to follow these steps again instead of the default update instructions.**

Comment: @user3651520 - I hope this helped. If so, could you please accept this as an useful answer ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3651520 - Please help accept it as the answer and vote up as now you've got the sufficient reputation. That will encourage new learners like me to contribute more in SO and help others

Answer (score 4):

After I installed some updated packages through the Android SDK Manager ADT posted an error message saying that I needed to update to 22.6.3. However, when I ran "Help / Check for Updates" it said "No updates were found." When I tried to compile my Android project I got similar errors to those posted above.

I followed Ramakishna's advice and went to http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html to review the official Android instructions on "Installing the Eclipse Plugin." I found that my ADT "Help / Install New Software..." dialog was using the wrong path to the update site. The Android instructions clearly state that "https://" is required.

- Was using: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
- Now using: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

When I made this change the install worked flawlessly with no errors, and I didn't need to manually download a zip file.

Comment: Yup, gotta copy the https ssl version of the path from their site. Kinda dumb that they don't include it in the bundle automatically. However for some reason even after updating it still says 22.6.2 on the ADT splash/loading screen lol.

Comment: @DanDalton you deserve the Nobel prize for this 'https' vs 'http' subtle distinction. Thank you for saving my life. :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it by going to Help -> Install New Software -> add then changing the android eclipse plugin url protocol from https:// to http://

Gotta love Eclipse..

Comment: Too funny lol.. Still not sure why the splash screen version won't change.