# Android ADT 23 Update - Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency

Tags: android, adt

First, ADT update errors are frequently asked but I have tried to do everything mentioned in those other Question-threads but no success (with https and without, ADT23.zip download too).

This is what I got when trying to update:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android DDMS 23.0.0.1245622 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.feature.group 23.0.0.1245622)
  Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Dalvik Debug Monitor Service 23.0.0.1245622 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms 23.0.0.1245622)
    Dalvik Debug Monitor Service 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: ADT Package 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 22.6.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Developer Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group [22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android DDMS 23.0.0.1245622 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.feature.group 23.0.0.1245622)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms [23.0.0.1245622]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android DDMS 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms [22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: They renamed ".feature" to ".feature.feature", that's why uninstall and re-install is required.

Comment: Here is the bug report:https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72584, the bug is in versions 23.0.0, 23.0.1 and 23.0.2; it is not fixed yet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and resolved it by uninstalling the previous version of ADT completely and then installing the new version.

Try it out.

Comment: I did it how you said and it worked for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: uninstall means just deleting older adt dir or is there anything else we need to please help me?

Comment: Look at the answer given by @user3775520, u can either revert back or remove ADT completely and then install it again

Comment: It's important to note you must ALSO remove Tracer for OpenGL ES, since it's part of the dependencies of ADT (and thus also conflicts with the new packages). I could only force the download through eclipse manager after removing both anything Android and this

Answer (score 5):

It works for me :)

If for some reason you installed an ADT preview and need to revert back to the current stable, you can't use the dialog to install "new" software since what you want is actually an older one. Instead do this:

- Open Help > About Eclipse... on Windows or Linux. On Mac, use the
  app's menu > About...
- Click the "Installation Details" button.
- Select the "Installation History" tab.
- Select one of the previous configurations.
- Click the "Revert" button at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: It also save my time...!

Comment: I have tried but not working. please help me its urgent. It says `Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.`

Comment: @PratikButani, what I did was make a backup of my entire Eclipse folder. Then I went to "Installation Details", as mentioned above, but I went to the Installed Software tab and clicked on "Android Development Toolkit" and then clicked "Uninstall". Then I copied as few files from my Eclipse folder as I could to get it running in a minimal state. Then I finally used "Install New Software" with https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse to get it to work. Hacky, but working.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded Eclipse Luna without ADT. This is important.

Depending on where you saved your workspace and what version of eclipse you were using before a pop up might come up saying that it will migrate to Eclipse Luna etc2. I chose to migrate to Luna.

I then went to help -> install new software and added the ADT plugin via https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse.

I have run my app I was developing on ADT 22.xx and it runs fine on the emulator and my own nexus 5.

I hope this helps.....

Answer (score -1):

I was using Eclipse Luna. I downloaded SDK 23. Then when I read ADT 23 released I was excited. I downloaded it too. But I relised it has many errors. I couldn't do anything with eclipse. I thought the other one, ADT 22 was good.

So I started to use Kepler again. I install  SDK 22.6.2 and ADT 22.6.2 too. I am happy now. I have no errors anymore.

If it is running, do not touch it!

Answer (score -2):

You have to Update your Google ADT to the Latest Version!

In Eclipse go to Help

Install New Software ---> Add

inside Add Repository write:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Double click in the opening Box the 1 entry.

Follow the Eclipse instructions.

After loading some time you will get the newest Developer Tools and NDK Plugins

Repeat this for 2 times

Tom

Comment: Simply he is trying to update from this site, but it is a bug in ADT 23,see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72584

Comment: Yes, I had the same Problem, but you have then to Update the Google ADT to the correct Version with the steps described in my Answer above. Tom.