# Android NDT in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to build an Android development environment on my PC. But I'm encountering some problems, and desperately need help. Operating System: Windows 7 (64 bit)
Installed component:

- Version: Kepler Service Release 2

I've tried to install the Android Native Development Tools but the following error message
appaer on then screen:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Native Development Tools 
  22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.
  group 22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357)
  Missing requirement: Android Native Development Tools 
  22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk.feature.group
  22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357) requires 'org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 0.0.0'
  but it could not be found
```

please can somebody help me solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar solution for eclipse indigo worked for me:
[Installing ADT on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419858/installing-adt-on-eclipse)

Try using the same method.